# How to use an Azure AD SSO access token to sign in on another website on a new browser

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, access-token

I have set up an AAD SSO enabled website A that gets an access token once the user logs in.  Now, the user has the option to navigate to website B, but on a new browser that doesn't have access to the session of the browser that website A was opened.

Is there a way for website B (.NET MVC Azure hosted Web App) to be setup to accept the access token (for example: through headers) to authenticate the user and establish a newly AAD SSO logged in user on the new browser?  (Users can't re-enter their credentials)

Comment: Website B could imlemened an OIDC relying party, please see https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html, if Azure AD is used as OIDC provider.
Website B could also implement an SAML Service Provider as Azure AD can also act as SAML Identity Provider.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, access tokens enable clients to securely call protected APIs, so it should be stored in backend. More often we use refresh token and access token at the same time to prevent the access token expiring.

On the other hand, if I have entered the credentials in one browser, then the identity platform knew the request came from me because some information would stored in my cookie of the website, but if I used another browser to visit IDP, it was impossible to let IDP know the request came from me, because I can't share cookie infomation with different browsers.

I find 2 videos on introducing SSO, I think they will help, here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-single-sign-on#single-sign-on-with-web-applications).

Hope it will do some help.

Comment: Acctually OAuth2 is about delegated authorization, i.e. accessing APIs on behalf of some user.
If it comes to SSO, actually an identity layer is needed, hence use OIDC.